# Player's class does not serialize properly

Tags: java, serialization, null

For the past few days I have been trying to work with serialization in order to save my game's state. I'm rather new to serialization so I've been practicing by trying to serialize my players data to a file called "Player.ser". As of right now when the player is deserialized it results in the player being null. When I run the serialize code it successfully creates the file and doesn't throw any exceptions and when I deserialize it it doesn't throw any exceptions either. Just before I write the file I change the name of the player so I know it has saved, however when I deserialize it and get the loaded players name it returns null.

This is my player code:

```
package entity;

import item.Item;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Random;
import quests.Quest;
import map.tiles.VoidTile;

public class EntityPlayer extends entity implements Serializable{

public EntityPlayer(int x, int y, String name, int width, int height, int[] pxArry){        
    super(x,y);

    this.direction = 0;
    this.name = name;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.pxArry = pxArry;

    for(int i = 0; i < pxArry.length; i++)
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < pxArry[i].length; i2++){
        this.pxArry[i][i2] = pxArry[i][i2];
    }

    this.inventory = new Item[0];

    this.createBasicStatsArry();
}

Item[] inventory;
Quest[] activeQuests, completedQuests;
Status[] statusArry[];

@Override
public String toString(){

    return "EntityPlayer [x=" + this.x +", y="+ this.y+", name="+ this.name+ ", width="+ this.width+", height="+this.height+", pxArry="+ this.pxArry+"]";
    }
}
```

here is my serializer code that runs when the player saves the game:

```
try {
    EntityPlayer tp= game.getPlayer();
    tp.setName("oldPlayer");
    ObjectOutputStream obs = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(new File("Player.ser")));

    obs.writeObject(tp);
    obs.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

here is my deserializer code:

```
if(new File("Player.ser").exists()){

    try {
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Player.ser"));
        try {

            EntityPlayer player = (EntityPlayer) oi.readObject();
            System.out.println("My name is: "+player.getName());
            oi.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }else{

        playerBlaze = new EntityPlayer(0,0,"Player",32,34,new int[][]{ar.makeImg("entityBlaze.png", 32, 34),ar.makeImg("entityClay.png", 32, 34)}, new int[]{1,100,100,5,5,5,5}, new int[]{1,100,100,5,5,5,5});
        player = playerBlaze;
        System.out.println("My name is "+player.getName());
    }
```

As I said earlier I'm new to using Serialization so it would be very helpful to know what's wrong with this code. Also if you know of any resources to learn about serialization or just java in general I would love to hear about them.

Comment: Simplify and solve. Try to serialize with a simpler class, one that has only a name String, and then see what happens. If it works, great, keep adding on to the class until you get what you want. If it doesn't, well then you can ask a much better question by posting code that is small, compiles for us, runs for us and demonstrates your problem for us -- a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EntityPlayer player = (EntityPlayer) oi.readObject();
```

You are shadowing the class member with this local variable declaration, so the class member doesn't change when you execute this line.

Comment: Wow I didn't notice that. I managed to fix my issue. I was actually calling playerBlaze instead of player when I was adding the player to the map. Since player was the one who was getting serialized, playerBlaze was null.